# How to remove all rows by a value in Column

Tags: r

How would I remove all rows containing the numeric '0' in Farmland across the entire data?

example of data:

```
dat <- read.csv("Bird_Dataset_2019.csv")
df <- aggregate(Farmland~ Species + Year + GRIDREF, data = dat, subset = Species == 'Turtle Dove', sum)
```

[image]

I have tried this code `df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) any(df > 1)), ]` but it returns the original dataset with warnings.

I expect looping and removing all rows by ID that have 0 in Farmland.

Comment: Please read the instructions for posting at the top of the [tag:r] tag page. In particular please provide the input in a form that can be copied and pasted into R, not as images and show the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `apply` function, you can do:

```r
df = df[df$Farmland !=0,]
```

or

```r
df = df[df$Farmland > 0,]
```